# Copy std::map of std::unique_ptr with polymorphic content

Tags: c++, copy, c++14, unique-ptr

I have a graph with an edge-class. I want edges to be copyable, but the problem is that the edge contains a `std::map` of `std::unique_ptr` of polymorphic content.
I have a base-class for edge-information. If an edge needs some extra-information, i can make a subclass of this information class and add it to the edge. This information is then stored in the map with the type of the information as key.

```
class Edge {
private:
    std::size_t from;
    std::size_t to;
    std::map<std::type_index, std::unique_ptr<EdgeInformation>> info;
public:
    Edge(std::size_t from, std::size_t to) : from(from), to(to) {
    }

    std::size_t start() const {
        return from;
    }

    std::size_t end() const {
        return to;
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void addInfo(Args&&... args) {
        info[typeid(T)] = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    template <typename T>
    bool hasInfo() {
        return info.find(typeid(T)) != info.end();
    }
    template <typename T>
    T getInfo() {
        return info[typeid(T)];
    }
    template <typename T>
    void removeInfo() {
        info.erase(std::remove(info.begin(), info.end(), typeid(T)), info.end());
    }

    Edge flipped() const {
        auto flipped_edge = Edge{to, from};
        for(auto &entry : info) {
            // add info to flipped edge here!
        }
        return flipped_edge;
    }
};
```

At the bottom, you see the function flipped() which should return the edge with start and end reversed. My current problem is that i don't know how to copy the info-map of my edge.

My EdgeInformation is just a base-class without any fields or methods.

Comment: `EdgeInformation` should have `Clone`.

Comment: @DimChtz i don't want to reverse my info-map. I just need a copy of it.

Comment: Your `getInfo` is wrong Btw, type mismatches.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah, you are right with getInfo, thank you for the hint. A clone method is a good idea. I will build that. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jarod42 stated right, i just had to add a clone method to my EdgeInformation class. So my flipped() method can be now written as:

```
Edge flipped() const {
    auto flipped_edge = Edge{to, from};
    for(auto &entry : info) {
        flipped_edge.info[entry.first] = entry.second->clone();
    }
    return flipped_edge;
}
```

Thank you alot.